# R double dot special identifiers

Tags: r

Can anybody point any good doc about double dot special identifiers? Below the context described. Some example how to produce double dot:

```
l <- list()
f <- function(x, y, z){
  l <<- c(l, list(match.call()))
  x[y][z]
}
invisible(lapply(list(1:2,3:4), f, c(TRUE,TRUE), c(TRUE,FALSE)))
l
# [[1]]
# FUN(x = X[[i]], y = ..1, z = ..2)
# 
# [[2]]
# FUN(x = X[[i]], y = ..1, z = ..2)
```

I've found them only mentioned in [R-lang](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) without much explanation.
I assume they just only points to the index of argument passed in `...` but I would like to read some more about it.

I was trying to use `sys.call` and later in post-processing use `match.call` on captured call but in above example it ends up with losing any lapply `...` arguments, and in the another example where function was a primitive generic I end up with error `... used in a situation where it does not exist`.
`match.call` used directly in my function without going into `sys.call` and later `match.call` seems to be only way to catch some info about arguments or avoid error in such cases.
So I would prefer to understand it more deeply, hopefully without going into R source.

PS. `match.call` was updated in R 3.2.0. The codes above were produced on R 3.2.0.

Comment: Asking for a reference to a doc really isn't a great question. It's better to ask more directly what you want to know about the double dots. The R-lang definition gives as much as it can. They are mentioned in the [R-intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument) with further discussion of dots in the `?dotMethods` help page.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your comment, will follow your advice. Didn't you wrote any book? I would be first to buy it :) I learned much from your answers about more internal-ish R processes!